# Get-ChildItem File Sorting

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a script that I run at my work that uses `get-childitem` to get all the files of a certain type in a storage drive and sorts and moves them to an archive drive. I'd like to automate this process to run once everyday but I realized I would have a problem in doing so.

Occasionally, when this script is run a file or two will still be in the process of transferring over to our storage drive. If I let the script move this file while it is still being transferred from our customer, it gets corrupted and won't open later.

I know how to filter based on file type and date and other basic parameters, but I'm not entirely sure how I tell this script to exclude files that are currently growing in size.

Below is what I'm currently using to filter what I want to move:

```
$TargetType = "*.SomeFileType"
$TargetDrive = "\\Some\UNC\Path"

Get-ChildItem $targetdrive\$targettype | ForEach-Object {$_.fullname} | Sort-Object | out-file $outStorageMove
```

Also, at the moment I'm putting everything that `get-childitem` finds into a text file, that gets invoked later so that I can manually edit what I want it to move. I'd like to get rid of this step if at all possible.

Comment: About the only way to do this over a network share that I can think of would be to pull a list of files, wait a fixed amount of time, then pull the list of files again and look for files whose length has changed.  Then, if the length of a given file hasn't changed, move it.  Alternately, you could keep looping and waiting until no changes are detected and then do the move.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `Copy-Item` CmdLet? `Copy-Item -Path $targetdrive\$targettype -Destination  $outStorageMove`

Comment: I'm not using `copy-item` there because I don't want to copy the items. I actually want to move them so that they aren't in the storage location. I just need this portion of the script to create a list of the files to move and then the back-half of the script matches the files with their corresponding locations based on a set of strings I have entered into a handful of variables.

I appreciate the idea thought, truly.

Answer (score 0):

So, move is essentially copy and delete.

So, like gvee state, Copy-Item is a better option, to get you past your stated concern, monitor for the copy to complete. My addition would be to delete once the copy is done and you have verified the copy.

Or use Bits as a job to do this.

Using Windows PowerShell to Create BITS Transfer Jobs
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663885(v=vs.85).aspx
You can use PowerShell cmdlets to create synchronous and asynchronous Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) transfer jobs.

All of the examples in this topic use the Start-BitsTransfer cmdlet. To use the cmdlet, be sure to import the module first. To install the module, run the following command: Import-Module BitsTransfer. For more information, type Get-Help Start-BitsTransfer at the PowerShell prompt.